# i am getting an error Argument 2 may not be passed with ref keyword while using ado.net

Tags: c#, reference, ado.net

```
int? t = 0;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Res", ref t);
```

I get an error in the second line:

> argument 2 may not be passed with ref keyword.

Answer (score 10):

You can only pass an argument by reference with `ref` if the *parameter* is a `ref` parameter as well. `AddWithValue` doesn't have any `ref` parameters, so you can't use it that way. Note that you *have* to specify `ref` when calling a method if a parameter has the `ref` modifier. So:

```
public void WithRef(ref int x) {}
public void WithoutRef(int x) {}

...


int y = 0;
// Valid
WithRef(ref y);
WithoutRef(y);
// Invalid
WithRef(y);
WithoutRef(ref y);
```

Basically, there's no way of telling an ADO.NET command parameter to track the current value of a variable - after all, that variable could be a local variable which will be "gone" by the time you use the command.

Instead, just compute the right value and then set it for the parameter value.